# PRISM + TabControl + Validation = Pain

Tags: c#, validation, prism, tabcontrol, idataerrorinfo

In my application I have dialogs with mutiple tabs. Im using `Prism` to register the views with the `TabControl`.

**What I want is a validation for the entire dialog to diable/enable the save button.**

The Problem: Currently we have a view-triggered validation. Means every bound item implements the `IDataErrorInfo` interface. When the **View is displayed** the binding triggers the interface and displays and error on the UI. The `Control` has the `HasError` Property set to true, save button gets disabled.

But the validation does not get tiggered until the view is displayed. Should I move the validation to the `ViewModel` and validate the `Properties` on my own or is there a solution to validate **inactive** views in a `TabControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't quite enough information to go off of I your question, so I can only guess.  First off, you must understand that there are no inactive views in a TabControl.  There is only one view in the TabControls visual tree at one time, and that is the selected tab.  This means the other views are removed from the visual tree until they are selected.  This really doesn't matter though, as validation is controlled via the ViewModel.  You ViewModel most likely has a Command bound to your Save button.  This command should have a CanExecute defined returning IDataErrorInfo.Error != null (meaning you have no errors).  This is where you will check the validity of your objects.  Return false if you have any errors, and true if you don't.  Hook into the property changed event of your objects, and call the SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChange method to recheck the state of your button.

If each view a tab has it's own ViewModel, hence it's own Save command, I would recommend using a CompositeCommand.  This is really an unknown since I don't know how you have architected your dialogs, views, or ViewModels.

Comment: Hello Brian, thanks for your answer. The problem here is that the Objects implement the IDataErrorInfo on their own. Means the ViewModel is not involved in any validation at the moment. The problem is I cannot track the validation status properly. It seems I need to move the validation from the objects to the viewmodel itself...

Comment: No you don't.  You just need to hook into the PropertyChange event of your objects and raise the RaiseCanExecuteChanged method.  This will raise the CanExecute of the command in your ViewModel.  This is where you can return true or false based on the state of your objects.

Comment: Thats right, I will try this! Is there a possibility to "highliht" the tab where controls are bound to the property causing validation error without displaying it? I was thinking about getting all the bindings and then look for the property which caused the validation error.

Comment: Yes this should be possible.  Just create a style for the TabItemHeader which will change what you want based on your bound data